# How to do a groupBy on unique items

Tags: scala

If I have the following data:

```
List (
   Color("red", "43"), 
   Color("red", "53"), 
   Color("red", "63"), 
   Color("red", "43")
)
```

If I do `val myMap: Map[String, List[Color]] = myList.groupBy(_.id)` on the above, I get the below:

```
Map(
   "43" -> List(Color("red", "43"), Color("red", "43")),
   "53" -> List(Color("red", "53")),
   "63" -> List(Color("red", "63"))
)
```

Instead of the above, how can I do a `groupBy` only on unique items. Ultimately, getting the following:

```
Map(
   "43" -> List(Color("red", "43")),
   "53" -> List(Color("red", "53")),
   "63" -> List(Color("red", "63"))
)
```

Comment: Does it have to be a `groupBy`? Your example is simple enough to solve just with `map`: `val map: Map [String, Color] = list.map(c => c.id -> c)(collection.breakout)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert the group to a `Set` to get *unique* elements only.

```
myList.groupBy(_.id).mapValues(_.toSet)
```

Or, as noted by Dima, if you want to preserve the group as a `List` use distinct.

```
myList.groupBy(_.id).mapValues(_.distinct)
```

Comment: Can I maintain the definition of `myMap` in my question, which is `Map[String, List[Color]]` Instead of `Map[String, Set[Color]]` which your answer would provide?

Comment: @Anthony IMHO the `Set` type better conveys the uniqueness property. But if for some external reasons you have to match the type, just change it to `.mapValues(_.toSet.toList)`

Comment: As @SerGr said, IMHO too if you want to ensure that something only have unique elements it must be a `Set`. Or if you really need it to be a `List` use the code provided by Serg.

Comment: You don't need to convert to set and back to get distinct elements. `.mappValues(_.distinct)` will do.

Comment: Thanks! @Dima, I always forget that method, Anthony if you really need a `List` that would be more clear and would require one less traversal,  rather than `toSet.toList`.

Comment: If you turn it around a bit, you have less intermediate collections (less garbage): `myList.distinct.groupBy(_.id)`